# Remove rows in a DataFrame that correspond to False values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Below is a df of formulas:

```
          formula
0              Ac
1       Ac(AgO2)2
2       Ac(AsO2)2
3       Ac(AuO2)2
4        Ac(BO2)2
...           ...
695606     ZrZnW3
695607     ZrZnW4
695608    ZrZnWAu
695609     ZrZnWC
695610    ZrZnWSe

[694398 rows x 1 columns]
```

I have checked the validity of each of these formulas and have created a list called `vals` that is the same length as this df with True and False values corresponding to each formula. I want to remove the rows in the df that are False. Right now I have `df.drop(df[vals].index, inplace = False)` which outputs the False formulas but I want the True ones

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. This should be the right syntax where `:` means "all columns"

```
df = df[vals,:]
```

Comment: that didn't work. Am I still supposed to use .drop()?

Comment: assuming that `vals` is a boolean mask (list of `True`s and `False`s), you shouldn'y.

Comment: It worked when I did `df = df[vals]`. I only have one column in the df

Comment: Great! Now you also know how you could do it with more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the list vals indeed consists of boolen values True or False, instead of maybe their strings like 'True' or 'False'. If it is indeed a boolean list, then this should simply work

```
vals = [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False]
df[vals]
```

returns

```
0   Ac
3   Ac(AuO2)2
4   Ac(BO2)2
6   ZrZnW3
8   ZrZnWAu
9   ZrZnWC
```

Comment: Yes, it was a list of Boolean values, and that worked. Thanks!